# Reactive forms: Radio button selects both

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form with Radio buttons. That radio buttons look like this:

```
  <label [for]="question.id + '_' + selectableValue.id"
    *ngFor="let selectableValue of selectableValues">
    <input
      type="radio"
      [id]="question.id + '_' + selectableValue.id"
      [value]="selectableValue.id"
      [formControl]="formControlToUse"
      [formControlName]="question.id"
      name="{{ question.id }}"
      (change)="execChange($event)"
    >
    {{selectableValue.displayName}}
  </label>
```

all variables are existing and are correctly resolved. `question.id` is unique per Question (one question consists of several radios (= sleectable values).

However, when I click a radio button, the other one is not getting unchecked-> Both are selected. BUT: The name is the same among the radios.

Can anyone help me out please?

@Update:
Please see the generated DOM here. Here you can see that the names are basically the same. Still, both checkboxes can be selected for some strange reason...

[image]

Comment: the name has to same for both the radio buttons

Comment: I understand you're saying the `value` for each should be unique, but this was my issue when it was occurring for me. Not sure if you have found a solution to this by now, but that might be worth exploring a bit more if not.

Answer (score 3):

You must give the same formControlName to your group of radio. You can remove `name` attribute since you use `formControlName`.

Complete example:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <div [formGroup]="form">
            <div *ngFor="let question of questions">
                <label [for]="question.id + '_' + selectableValue.id" *ngFor="let selectableValue of selectableValues">
                    <input type="radio"
                           [id]="question.id + '_' + selectableValue.id"
                           [value]="selectableValue.id"
                           [formControlName]="question.id">
                    {{selectableValue.displayName}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
})
export class AppCp {
    form: FormGroup;
    questions = [{id: 'id1'}, {id: 'id2'}];
    selectableValues = [
        {id: 1, displayName: 'first'},
        {id: 2, displayName: 'second'}
    ];

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        let group = {};
        this.questions.forEach(q => group[q.id] = '');
        this.form = fb.group(group);
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: question.id is the same name for the set. It must be dynamic. Still not working unfortunately...

Comment: Yes i missing some things. I will update soon. You are using  ReactiveFormsModule ?

Comment: I did it exaclty the same way as you... I added a screenshot showing that the names are the same... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the complete component code with variables values. It's hard to help you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue. What I was missing was the Name property in the radio buttons.
Both the Radio buttons should have Name property and Name should be same for both the radio button.

Below is my Example:

component.html

```
      <div class="col-md-8 form-group">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input class="form-control"
               id="rdoNew"
               type="radio"
               name="newOrUsed1"
               formControlName="newOrUsed" value="new" />
        New
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input class="form-control"
               id="rdoUsed"
               type="radio"
               name="newOrUsed1"
               formControlName="newOrUsed" value="used" />
        Used
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Component.ts

```
export class AutoloanComponent implements OnInit {
```

`loanInfoGroup: FormGroup;`

`constructor() { }`

`ngOnInit() {`
    `this.loanInfoGroup = new FormGroup({`

```
  `newOrUsed: new FormControl(),`

});
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

for some crazy reason, using [attr.name] resolves this issue.  You need both [attr.name] and [formControlName] bound to the same value.  Perhaps this is another, more elegant solution, but I have not found it.

This is very late but hopefully this can help someone else who stumbles upon this problem.